# How to properly type a function lookup

Tags: typescript

Sorry if I wasn't clear on the title, just don't know how to ask it better...

Suppose I have an object of template functions and should select one template function to apply on some params:

```
type TemplateArgs = { arg1: string } | { arg2: string }

const templateFunctions = {
  template1: (args: {arg1: string}) => 'foo',
  template2: (args: {arg2: string}) => 'bar',
}

function templateLookup<K extends keyof T, T>(type: K, templateFunctions: T) {
  return templateFunctions[type]
}

// I only know which template key and params on runtime
const templateKey = ['template1' as const, 'template2' as const][Math.round(Math.random())]

const rightTemplate = templateLookup(templateKey, templateFunctions)

// just mocking the params
const templateParams: TemplateArgs = { arg2: '2'}

const result = rightTemplate(templateParams)
//                           ^ Argument of type '{ arg2: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ arg1: string; } & { arg2: string; }'. 
//                             Property 'arg1' is missing in type '{ arg2: string; }' but required in type '{ arg1: string; }'.
```

How can I determine that `rightTemplate`'s and `templateParams`'s types are the same? I know that `templateParams` should be either `{ arg1: string }` or `{ arg2: string }`, but `rightTemplate` requires an intersection of the two. How do I properly type this code?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=11&pc=33#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhC2YA2BDYECCAnA5gZygF4oBvKFXARgC4o9gsBLAOxygF8oAfU83AJlr0mrDgCgxAYwD2zelHSJU6AGIBXZpOCNZBYiTFQFCZGgg0oACgr5aJGxeEsc7AJREAfFADkAM2nS3gA0hsZKZoJWNnh2NpFOrG6ePgBGFMFi7BKgkLAmyhAw4BB6UADWECDSvgrF1WGmqhpaOnISvs3asg0FADIBZWpgljkQtHDh6EWQeO4GRlgQwGpYzD1m6ppdcgDaowC6mRIycsDr6AAKFCjwMXmTmLilZHG03vzeWVK6Z0w4ABbACaNaDERQg-rSQbDbzggofVzHH5QRZ4NRIM7EP6A4EFEb5MxXLA3WZAA)

Comment: It's not about intersection type. You said it yourself, that the type of `rightTemplate` is only known at run time. So there is no way you know which parameters should be provided to it at compile time. Am I missing the point?

Comment: I mean, you can change your `TemplateArgs` definition do be intersection type instead of union - but is it really what you're trying to achieve?
```type TemplateArgs = { arg1: string } & { arg2: string };```. ```const templateParams: TemplateArgs = { arg2: '2', arg1: '1'}```

Comment: @amakhrov Yes, I agree, my question is how to properly type this code